# Uncaught (in promise) Error: Missing required param "tag" - Vue

Tags: vue.js

I use Vue 3.
I'm trying to create a dynamic tag list. But i have a problem with the code.

```
<div class="d-inline-block" >
    <router-link v-for="item in profile.tahs.split(',')" v-bind:key="item" 
        :to="{ name: 'tag', params: { tag: `${item}` } }" >
    <span class="badge rounded-pill bg-secondary" style="margin: 1px;">{{ item }}</span></router-link> 
                            
</div>
```

List of tags render normally. But route to each tag is wrong and i get error
"vue-router.esm-bundler.js?ec2d:1004 Uncaught (in promise) Error: Missing required param "tag"

i tried do this:

```
`${item[0]}`
```

and this show me first letter of tag. So, item isn't empty.

I want to make each tag with route to this tag. How to fix this

Comment: ok i solve this. I had a comma after last tag in django admin

Comment: Unrelated, but the template literals are unnecessary in this case. It can be used in place of string concatenation, but you're not doing that. You can just do: `params: { tag: item }` and avoid the overhead of having to process the template literals.